# Split character and numeric string with NAs

Tags: r

For an example dataframe:

```
df <- structure(list(ID = 1:6, region = structure(c(5L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 
                                                    6L, 2L), .Label = c("AB1", "AB22", "AC225", "AF32", "AX11", "OI222"
                                                    ), class = "factor"), level = c(2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L)), .Names = c("ID", 
                                                                                                                         "region", "level"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L
                                                                                                                         ))
```

I have a column called region with at least two character variables infront, and then either 1, 2 or 3 numeric variables.  The level variable denotes how big the region is (where level 1 represents the largest regions in countries and level 3 contains the smallest regions).

The region codes detail not only what region each ID refers to, but often (where applicable) the larger regions which are linked.

For example, AC225 is:
AC in region 0; AC2 in region 1; AC22 in region 2; AC225 in region 3.

I wish to do this for each of the ID variables using the region code.  Things are complicated slightly as for some IDs, I will not know the region 2 or 3 (and I then would wish NAs to be added).  For example, for AB32 I would want AB for region.0, AB3 for region.1, AB32 for region.2 and NA for region.3.

I tried to use the stringr function, but haven't had much success:

```
library(stringr)
df$region.0 <- str_sub(df$region,1,2)
df$region.1 <- str_sub(df$region,1,2,3)
df$region.2 <- str_sub(df$region,1,2,3,4)
df$region.3 <- str_sub(df$region,1,2,3,4,5)
```

If anyone could help me, I should be most grateful.

Comment: If 'region' can have "at least two character variables infront" (e.g. 2 or 3 letters), you might provide sample data which reflect this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe try with `stringi` and `regex`:

```
library("stringi")

df$region.0 <- stri_extract_all_regex(df$region, "^..")
df$region.1 <- stri_extract_all_regex(df$region, "^...")
df$region.2 <- stri_extract_all_regex(df$region, "^....")
df$region.3 <- stri_extract_all_regex(df$region, "^.....")

> df
  ID region level region.0 region.1 region.2 region.3
1  1   AX11     2       AX      AX1     AX11       NA
2  2  AC225     3       AC      AC2     AC22    AC225
3  3    AB1     1       AB      AB1       NA       NA
4  4   AF32     2       AF      AF3     AF32       NA
5  5  OI222     3       OI      OI2     OI22    OI222
6  6   AB22     2       AB      AB2     AB22       NA
```

Comment: Unless my memory is absolutely faulty, `stringi` is included in `stringr`, and not using any case here, `str_extract_all` would do the job as well

Comment: Yes, I've checked it - you're right. But I didn't knew the `stringr` package earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Another way, with `gsub` and `mapply` from base R.

The number of uppercase letters prior to the digits doesn't matter and it avoids having to type as many lines as there are "new" columns to add:

```
maxlevel <- 3 # you can have more later if you wish to

res <- cbind(df, 
            `colnames<-`(t(mapply(function(x, y){
                                     c(gsub("^([A-Z]+)\\d+$", "\\1", x), 
                                       sapply(1:y, 
                                            function(n){
                                              gsub(paste0("^([A-Z]+\\d{",n,"})\\d*$"), "\\1", x)}), 
                                       rep(NA, maxlevel-y))}, 
                                  df$region, df$level)), 
                          paste("region", 0:maxlevel, sep=".")))
res
#  ID region level region.0 region.1 region.2 region.3
#1  1   AX11     2       AX      AX1     AX11     <NA>
#2  2  AC225     3       AC      AC2     AC22    AC225
#3  3    AB1     1       AB      AB1     <NA>     <NA>
#4  4   AF32     2       AF      AF3     AF32     <NA>
#5  5  OI222     3       OI      OI2     OI22    OI222
#6  6   AB22     2       AB      AB2     AB22     <NA>
```

***Explanation***

`mapply` takes the name of the region and the level to compute a vector composed of just the letters of the region's name, the letters and from 1 to `level` digit(s) and finally `NA` till a length equal to `maxlevel` is reached.